# How to add fallbacks to partial included with Sage 10's @include?

Tags: php, wordpress, roots-sage

Let's say I have created a button component I want to include into my project with Sage 10's `@include` function, how do I add fallbacks to the variables, in case I or another user forget to add a value?

My button*:

```
<button class="<?= esc_attr($button_class); ?>">
         <?= esc_html($button_label); ?>
</button>
```

My include

```
@include('partials.button', [
  'button_class' => 'btn btn-primary',
  'button_label' => 'label', 
])
```

How can I add fallbacks, so button isn't empty if I don't add `button_label`?

*Code is simplified for this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the external PHP-file, with the button, you can add the variables between some PHP-tags, to catch any empty variables and instead return a fallback.

In this case, the PHP-file with the `<button>` element would look like this:

```
<?php
  $button_class = $button_class ?: 'lg:block w-full lg:w-auto btn btn-primary mr-4';
  $button_label = $button_label ?: __( 'Insert text here', 'fallback', 'edc' );
?>

<button class="<?= esc_attr($button_class); ?>">
         <?= esc_html($button_label); ?>
</button>
```

Sage will first apply the variables from the `@include`-part to the variables in the top, after which PHP uses the value as is after the closing `?>`-tag.